# Backlight driver /sys/class/backlight has two entries?

Tags: 11.10, backlight

System: Dell N4110
Ubuntu ver: Oneric

My  `/sys/class/backlight`  has two entries  `acpi_video0`  and `intel_backlight`? Is it normal to have two entries here?

When I try to change the screen brightness using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Brightness</kbd>, the brightness changes with uneven steps. I'm suspecting the dual entries in the `/sys/class` folder is pointing to some issues?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have a newer Intel Sandy bridge processor in the Dell which has integrated graphics as well as a graphics card - that is the reason for the two entries in your `/sys/class/backlight` folder.

You can do two things - disable one of the graphics cards via the bios settings and see if it solves the problem or you can follow the instructions in this [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866283) post to blacklist one of the entries.

My first option would be to disable via bios and see if it is acceptable.

Comment: I couldn't find the BIOS setting to disable the graphics card. I'll give the second option a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Edit the following file as root:

/etc/default/grub

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then as root run:

/usr/sbin/update-grub

Then reboot and your brightness keys should function as expected.